# Please create an HL7-v2 tag

Tags: discussion, support

It would be great if an HL7-v2 tag could be created in order to tag posts related to HL7-v2 support queries. This would also separate out questions specifically targeted for HL7-v2 from those targeted for v3.

Comment: Now if just we knew what HL7-v2 actually is? :)

Comment: There are [176 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7) tagged hl7. However, I don't know anywhere near enough about it to go through and determine whether they need version specific tags, or if the existing hl7 tag is even related to what you're asking for.

Comment: @Pekka웃 [HL7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Level_7) is a special format that was created as an industry standard way of transferring health care data electronically. I created some HL7 file parsing tools recently, and know there is a significant difference between the different versions (v2 is most commonly used now, however v3 is the latest version), and its quite hard to find good documentation or help about the formats.

Comment: Vcuankit, if you find some questions specific to HL7 v2, then leave the link for me in a comment here and I'll retag them to [HL7-v2] to create the tag. I was wishing for the exact same thing when I was trying to build a HL7 parser a while back and browsing SO for questions specific to HL7 v2.

Comment: Thanks Rachel. I agree. The request actually came from someone else who commented on a SO post I created a while ago. I thought it was a great idea due to the vast difference in the two versions. The link is below.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964177/hl7-data-type-error

Answer (score 1):

If it's really a relevant tag for the site, it's going to come up organically eventually.

A tag will be automatically created when the first question with it comes up (asked by someone with 1500+ rep who can create tags.)